# Best/Fastest way to read meaningful data from an accelerometer sensor? (LSM9DS0)

Tags: javascript, socket.io, raspberry-pi, sensors, i2c

I am running a **expressjs** server on my Raspberry Pi. I am using the **i2c-bus** dependency to read data from the sensor and then I use **socket.io** to emit the data to the client. Right now I am reading data off the sensor 20 times, then averaging it, then emitting the averaged data to the client. I have used this technique to read around 2000 bytes in 55ms off the sensor using i2c. However, I know the i2c bus and the sensor can work much faster. Apparently i2c can read from 100kb/s to 400kb/s. I am only reading ~40kb/s which isn't bad but could be better.

I tried using a `readBlock()` method to read 32 bytes but I was just reading 32 bytes of the same value as the sensor had not updated its own value yet.

For anyone who has done a similar project, **what is the best way to read data from these types of sensors**?

Should I use:

- "continuous update",
- "output registers not updated until MSB and LSB have been read",
- "FIFO"?

Comment: You should use in-kernel driver. Unfortunately there is no in upstream, but there are projects on GitHub, including one from vendor (STMicro).

Comment: https://github.com/Lahorde/st_lsm9ds0_linux_driver, https://github.com/erlerobot/kernel_lsm9ds0 (uses input subsystem which is not recommended for new sensors), https://github.com/mpod/kernel-playground (better one, but from 3rd party).

Comment: @0andriy github.com/Lahorde/st_lsm9ds0_linux_driver looks like a winner but I have no idea how I would interact with the driver via javascript. a js version of execvp? Thanks for the reply btw.